# Stability of a falling object

Tags: torque, projectile, drag, aerodynamics, stability

Suppose there is a falling object that has flaps around it providing resistance to the non-contact force of gravity. How would the vehicle theoretically not flip over?

From my understanding, the flaps provide an upward force on the vehicle causing a net torque of zero. Algebraic explanations would help.

Comment: Flaps don't provide resistance to the force of gravity ... they provide air drag.  The direction of the force of air drag is opposite the direction of motion.  For objects traveling up, the direction of the air drag force is down, and vice versa.

Answer (score 0):

Flaps provide aerodynamic (velocity proportional) force. This is not directly related to gravity.

The aerodynamic force can have a net torque resultant different from zero.

Comment: Note, at higher speeds the air drag is not velocity proportional anymore, but rather proportional to the *square* of the speed.

Comment: @Steeven Is air drag ever linearly proportional to the velocity? I mean, squared is such a simple relation I see little point in trying to simplify it. I assume nodarkside's definition of "proportional" is more liberal than the mathematical definition of proportional in that all it means is " when one gets bigger the other gets bigger"

Comment: @DKNguyen Well, sure, you could argue for that. I just do see drag modelled linearly for low velocities from time to time. Squaring is maybe not that much more complicating but it still may be the difference between a linear and a non-linear equation system.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. What I meant is, if the velocity increase, the drag incrase. I didn't mean linearly proportional.